# django and AWS SES service settings 554 error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I set my settings :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'I got something from Amazon SES SMTP Settings Create My SMTP Credentials'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'I got something from Amazon SES SMTP Settings Create My SMTP Credentials'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

But When i use this to my django-allauth email verification,

There comes

```
SMTPDataError at /accounts/email/
(554, b'Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-WEST-2: webmaster@localhost')
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) to [one of the addresses verified in SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-addresses-and-domains.html).

Or alternatively you can pass `from_email` when calling [`send_mail()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/email/#send-mail) (and related).